# File Directory and Downloading File URL error

Tags: php

I am using the below code to read files I have saved on my server in folders.

```
<?php
    if ($handle1 = opendir('../files/policies/fire')) {
        while (false !== ($file1 = readdir($handle1))) {
            if ($file1 != "." && $file1 != "..") {
                $thelist1 .= '<li><a href="'.$file1.'" target="_blank">'.$file1.'</a></li>';
            }
        }
        closedir($handle1);
    }
?>
<h3>Fire Fighting Files:</h3>
<ul><?php echo $thelist1; ?></ul></h6>
```

The code reads the files in the directory as it should. The issue I am having is once I click the link it searches or attempts to open the file in the root directory

It does not use the sub-dir to open the file but the root dir. The structure is as follow

```
/File
  /policies
    /FA
```

When I click the link it tries finding the file as below

```
/files/OHS_EHSR-020%20Employee%20Health%20and%20Safety%20Rules.pdf
```

and the file is saved as

```
/files/policies/FA/OHS_EHSR-020%20Employee%20Health%20and%20Safety%20Rules.pdf
```

Any suggestions would help. Please note my code I am using I took from this site as well

ADDING Full Code of two blocks this is why I cannot fix the directories to static in my code:

```
<div class="col-xl-5 col-md-5 col-12">
            <div class="box box-body">
              <h6 class="text-uppercase">
                  <?php
                  if ($handle = opendir('../files/policies/FA')) {
                      while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
                          if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                              $thelist .= '<li><a href="'.$file.'" target="_blank">'.$file.'</a></li>';
                          }
                      }
                      closedir($handle);
                  }
                  ?>
                  <h3>First Aid Files:</h3>
                  <ul><?php echo $thelist; ?></ul></h6>
             </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
          <div class="col-xl-5 col-md-5 col-12">
              <div class="box box-body">
                  <h6 class="text-uppercase">
                      <?php
                      if ($handle1 = opendir('../files/policies/fire')) {
                          while (false !== ($file1 = readdir($handle1))) {
                              if ($file1 != "." && $file1 != "..") {
                                  $thelist1 .= '<li><a href="'.$file1.'" target="_blank">'.$file1.'</a></li>';
                              }
                          }
                          closedir($handle1);
                      }
                      ?>
                      <h3>Fire Fighting Files:</h3>
                      <ul><?php echo $thelist1; ?></ul></h6>
              </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Does this work => `'<li><a href="/files/policies/FA/'.$file1.'" target="_blank">'.$file1.'</a></li>';` ? Also, are you sure you would want to show actual file path of the server?

Comment: I do not want to show the path and I cannot fix the path as the files are in different directories

Comment: What happens if a user clicks the link? They download the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readdir` returns relative path not absolute, so you need to prepend `/files/policies` to the `$file` variable and use it in your link

update:

```
$dir = '/files/policies/fire';

if ($handle1 = opendir('..' . $dir)) {
  while (FALSE !== ($file1 = readdir($handle1))) {
    if ($file1 != "." && $file1 != "..") {
      $filepath = $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file1;
      $thelist1 .= '<li><a href="' . $filepath . '" target="_blank">' . $file1 . '</a></li>';
    }
  }
  closedir($handle1);
}
```

this should work for you